# changing to another background while playing game

Tags: ios, xcode, swift2

```
func createBackgrounds() {
    for i in 0...2 {
       let bg = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "BG Day")
       bg.name = "BG"
       bg.zPosition = 0;
       bg.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
       bg.position = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(i) * bg.size.width, y: 0)
       self.addChild(bg)
    }
}
```

If I want to add another background "BG Night" after 2 minutes while playing game, how can I write the codes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at NSTimer:

```
var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(120.0, target: self, selector: #selector(addBackground), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
```

Then, create an addBackground function that creates another background image.

Hope this helps!